# What is the minimum required SSL for facebook applications

Tags: facebook, https

I am going to buy SSL for my facebook application. I will buy the cheapest one. Which one is the cheapest accepted by facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self signed is the cheapest (free).  But most browsers would show a security warning before displaying the page.